# Is the basic policy here one post = one question?

Tags: discussion

I've seen several postings recently where the person asking the question in fact asks two (or more) questions in a single post.  (Example: [Setting up a download page requiring a user to fill a form before downloading anything](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/setting-up-a-download-page-requiring-a-user-to-fill-a-form-before-downloading-an))  Sometimes the questions are related and sometimes they are not.  However, although I couldn't find this in the faq anywhere, it seems to me that people really ought to only be asking one question per post.

One reason why is that if people are permitted to ask multiple questions in a single post and then different people answer different parts of the question, it becomes very difficult to pick an accepted answer.  Is it appropriate to kindly suggest to such users to post multiple questions in the future?

Answer (score 5):

The general consensus, at least on meta.stackoverflow.com (which I think it's safe to say speaks for all SE sites), is that **one post = one question**.

Rather than repeat the various arguments here, have a look at these:

- [What do we do with multiple question questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/what-do-we-do-with-multiple-question-questions)
- [FAQ suggestion: that a question should be a single question, self-contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122361/faq-suggestion-that-a-question-should-be-a-single-question-self-contained)
- [Multi-Question Questions: How Best to Handle Them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/multi-question-questions-how-best-to-handle-them)

This might be a good thing to add to our own FAQ thinking about it, hopefully one of the mods will see this and comment; if not I'll make the suggestion in another thread.